# What is the difference between abnormal cells and cancerous cells?

Tags: cancer, breast, biopsy, morphology, cells

When a biopsy reveals that cells are *"abnormal"* but not cancerous, what does that actually mean?

Comment: I'm no pathologist so I can't say for sure, but I suspect the answer would be that it could mean many things. From personal experience, I would treat any pathology report with vague language like that as highly suspicious and request a second opinion. I got a similar report on a biopsy from a dog once. It declared the cells normal but noted they had a "high mitotic rate." Yeah, they had a high mitotic rate alright because they were a very aggressive form of cancer the pathologist failed to identify.

Comment: @CareyGregory Thanks Carey.  That's a scary anecdote.  Sorry he/she didn't properly identify the cancer.